# Android text is in reversed order

Tags: android, arrays, json

As a result of the two for-loops below I should get the word an Album name, but I get this name in reverse order. For example if I expect "LINK", I get "KNIL"... Where am I going wrong?

Here is the code:

```
jsonobj = new JSONObject(param);
JSONObject datajson = jsonobj.getJSONObject("data");
JSONArray news = datajson.getJSONArray(TAG_NEWS);
JSONArray actual = datajson.getJSONArray("actual");
for(int i = 0; i < news.length(); i++){
    JSONObject c = news.getJSONObject(i);

    // Storing each json item in variable
    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
    String album = c.getString(TAG_ALBUM);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imgtest);
    //tv.setText(album);
    if(!(album == "null")){
        String var[] = album.split("|");
        for(int a=0;a<var.length;a++){
            String t = var[a].intern();
            String al = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.imgtest)).getText().toString();
            String b = t+al;
            tv.setText(b);
        }
    }else{
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the data in `datajson` look like?

Answer (score 2):

This line is adding the newest letter `t` to the beginning of your existing String `al`:

```
String b = t+al;
```

However rather than simply switching this line around (`b = al + t`), I recommend a *faster* method:

```
String album = c.getString(TAG_ALBUM).replaceAll("|", "");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imgtest);
tv.setText(album);
```

I looks like you only wanted to remove the "|" character from your `album` String, so just use [`String.replaceAll()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

---

If you need `album` split into an array, then when you rebuild the String don't waste your time calling `findViewById()` on a view that you already have. In fact you already have the String, so there is no need to use `getText()` either:

```
String var[] = album.split("|");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int a=0;a<var.length;a++)
    builder.append(a);

// use builder.toString() when you want the cleaned album name.
```

Comment: no that was just test , need to get that array , just tell me how to make that text in right order

Answer (score 0):

To add the latest letter `t` to the end of the current string `al`:

```
b = al + t
```